# QGIS - Hide some Symbols in a Shapelayer depending of the viewfield

Tags: qgis

How is it possible to hide some of the symbols, depending on the viewfield and zoom ?
I use the Rule-Based style to assign the colors and the direction of the arrows.

How it looks in qgis:
[Layer in QGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOgAw.jpg)

How it should looks like from qrcgis
[Layer in ArcGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBeLz.png)

Is it possible to hide a few of the arrows to gain a better overview?

Best regards
Kai

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it may be very easy in versions higher than 3.22, you can find more information about this type of QGIS symbology here: [Point Cluster Renderer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#point-cluster-renderer)

I don't know anything about the attributes that define the direction of the arrows you're dealing with, but I recommend you take a look at rotating symbols using extensions, maybe it can help.